# add RDFS inference rules support in endpoint SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rule, virtuoso, rdfs, inference

I have create an endpoint SPAQL on OpenLink Virtuoso.
All work well, but i have to access on the data in a Container, in particular a rdf:Seq.

I have a Seq like this:

```
 <myrdf:has_stoptimes>
  <rdf:Seq rdf:about="http://test.com/343">
    <rdf:li>
      <myrdf:StopTime rdf:about="http://test.com/StopTime/434">
           ...
      </ns0:StopTime>
    </rdf:li>
    <rdf:li>
      <myrdf:StopTime rdf:about="http://test.com/StopTime/435">
           ...
      </ns0:StopTime>
    </rdf:li>
  </rdf:Seq>
```

Now i see that to access data in a container i can use `rdfs:member` or  `FILTER (strstarts(str(?prop), str(rdf:_))` how is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121150/sparql-query-rdf-container-rdf-bag)

But for  my project i have to adopt the first solution because i'm working with [Silk](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/silk/wiki) and i will use the code syntax like `?a/myrdf:has_stoptimes/rdfs:member` without use of "complex" filter.

I have tried to follow this [guide](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlrule.html) but querying the endpoint nothing work how i hoped.

So my question is: how can i query `?a/myrdf:has_stoptimes/rdfs:member` on a Virtuoso endpoint SPARQL?Which inference rule i have to add in endpoint SPARQL?

Thank you in advance

---

**UPDATE**

I have created the following inference rules in Virtuoso:

```
ttlp (' @prefix rdfs:  .
        @prefix rdf:  .
  rdfs:Container rdf:type rdfs:Class ; rdfs:subClassOf rdfs:Resource .
  rdfs:ContainerMembershipProperty a rdfs:Class ; rdfs:subClassOf rdf:Property .
  rdf:Seq rdf:type rdfs:Class ; rdfs:subClassOf rdfs:Container .
  rdfs:member rdf:type rdf:Property ; rdfs:domain rdfs:Resource ; rdfs:range rdfs:Resource .
  ', '', 'http://localhost:8890/schema/test') ;
```

Nothing work querying the SPARQL endpoint like:

```
define input:inference "http://localhost:8890/schema/property_rules1"

       SELECT *
        FROM 
        WHERE {?sep a rdf:Seq.
        ?seq rdfs:member ?p}
```

After i tried adding the follow line to the ttl file: `rdf:_1 rdfs:subPropertyOf rdfs:member` . In this way it work but obviously the results are only for the first element of the container. So is very unconvenient add a line for all of `rdf:_n`, and i think this is only a temporary solution, it is not correct.

I have tried to add an RDF dump on SILK 2.6.1, and on the section SPARQL of the data source if i run the query:

```
 SELECT *
    FROM 
    WHERE {?sep a rdf:Seq.
    ?seq rdfs:member ?p}
```

I obtain the correct result, without specify any inference rules. So i think that in this functionality of SILK there is something that i’m missing in my endpoint SPARQL or am i saying nonsense things?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking.  Are you saying that you *want* to use property paths like `?a/has_stoptimes/rdfs:member`?

Comment: yes exactly sorry for my bad question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variables in property paths, so you can't actually do

```
?x ?a/has_stoptimes/rdfs:member ?y
```

Instead, you have to use another variable or blank node in between:

```
?x ?a ?z . ?z has_stoptimes/rdfs:member ?y
```

```
?x ?a [ has_stoptimes/rdfs:member ?y ] .
```

Comment: but my problem is that the endpoint SPARQL that receive my query don't recognize `rdfs:member` property so i can't operate on node of the container (rdf:Seq)

Comment: What is the actual error message? Did you declare the appropriate prefix?

Comment: yes all prefix are right, there aren't error messages. The problem is that my rdf has property like rdf:_1,rdf:_2..rdf:_n and the only way that i found to query via SPARQL the nodes of the rdf:Seq is through rdfs:member property. The SPARQL query generated by SILK is: `SELECT ?b ?v0 
FROM <http://example.com>
WHERE {
?b a <http://myrdf.com/Trip> .
OPTIONAL {
?b <http://myrdf.com/has_stoptimes> ?t1 .
?t1 <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#member> ?v0 .
}` So the problem is not SILK or its syntax because if i query directly on SPARQL endpoint via browser it don't work anyway.

Comment: i'm pretty sure that the problem is that i need to modify my endpoint SPARQL, like add inference rules but i don't know how, in particular which rule adds. I found an old document speaking about it but very generally [link old doc](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-rdf-dawg-comments/2007Jun/0005.html)

Comment: Ah, OK.  I see.  Sorry, I misunderstood the issue.  Would your data let you make the assumption that if something is a Seq, then all of its properties (aside from `rdf:type`) are `rdfs:_n` properties?  Then you could simply search for `:seq789 ?p ?element`.

Comment: I don't know because i'm not very expert of Virtuoso. But the main problem is that rdf:_1, rdf:_2...rdf:_n is not identifiable via SPARQL in a general way, i can only said `?s rdf:_1 ?o.` and this keep only the first element of a container.

Comment: right, and if you use rdfs:member, then you lose ordering information.  But if the seq *only* has rdf:_n properties, then you could just ask for *all* the properties, and then you'd essentially be getting rdfs:member.

Comment: yes sure but is here that enter Silk Framework because its [path input](https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/silk/Path_Input) accept only property after `/` "forward operator" so i have to usa a property that is general because i can't use rdf:_1, how i explain before. I need to use rdfs:member and if i lose ordering information is not a problem here.

Comment: @madbitbot Are you trying to write a Silk query or a SPARQL query?  The title asks about a SPARQL endpoint, and it sounds like the query is going to be run against a Virtuoso endpoint.  Then you can either use the SPARQL query and filter for the `_n` properties, or you can ask for *any* property (if there shouldn't be any others).  (All of those are options other than enabling RDFS inferencing.)

Comment: Yes the query is going to be run on a SPARQL endpoint but it start from a query write in SILK, so i don't have the full expressivity of normal filter. Is for that i'm trying to found a solution about rdfs:member using inference rules. Besides i tried to load a rdf dump in silk and query on in through silk SPARQL view, and here rdfs:member work well!!! So i think that is really a problem with my Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint.